# Why does sbt build fail with "MissingRequirementError: object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found."?

Tags: scala, sbt, multi-module

I have [this multi-module build configuration](https://github.com/mauricio/postgresql-async/blob/multi-module/project/Build.scala) that I'm trying to get working, but whenever I try to compile the project it fails with the following error:

```
➜  postgresql-netty git:(multi-module) sbt clean compile
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/mauricio/.sbt/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/mauricio/projects/scala/postgresql-netty/project
[info] Set current project to db-async-base (in build file:/Users/mauricio/projects/scala/postgresql-netty/)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed May 1, 2013 11:18:29 PM
[info] Updating {file:/Users/mauricio/projects/scala/postgresql-netty/}db-async-common...
[info] Updating {file:/Users/mauricio/projects/scala/postgresql-netty/}db-async-base...
[info] Resolving org.specs2#scalaz-core_2.10;7.0.0 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/Users/mauricio/projects/scala/postgresql-netty/}postgresql-async...
[info] Resolving ch.qos.logback#logback-classic;1.0.9 ...
[info] Compiling 16 Scala sources to /Users/mauricio/projects/scala/postgresql-netty/db-async-common/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[info] Resolving org.specs2#scalaz-core_2.10;7.0.0 ...
[info] Done updating.
scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found.
    at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:16)
    at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:17)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:48)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:40)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:61)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getPackage(Mirrors.scala:172)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getRequiredPackage(Mirrors.scala:175)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RuntimePackage$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:181)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RuntimePackage(Definitions.scala:181)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RuntimePackageClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:182)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RuntimePackageClass(Definitions.scala:182)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.AnnotationDefaultAttr$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1015)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.AnnotationDefaultAttr(Definitions.scala:1014)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.syntheticCoreClasses$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1144)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.syntheticCoreClasses(Definitions.scala:1143)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.symbolsNotPresentInBytecode$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1187)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.symbolsNotPresentInBytecode(Definitions.scala:1187)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1252)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1289)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:87)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:72)
    at xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:73)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:35)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:29)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(AggressiveCompile.scala:71)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:71)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:71)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.sbt$compiler$AggressiveCompile$$timed(AggressiveCompile.scala:101)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4.compileScala$1(AggressiveCompile.scala:70)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:88)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$4.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:60)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:24)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:22)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$.cycle(Incremental.scala:52)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:29)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:20)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile2(AggressiveCompile.scala:96)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile1(AggressiveCompile.scala:44)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:31)
    at sbt.Compiler$.apply(Compiler.scala:79)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:574)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:574)
    at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf2$1.apply(Structure.scala:578)
    at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf2$1.apply(Structure.scala:578)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49)
    at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
    at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:41)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$5.work(System.scala:71)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:238)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
[error] (db-async-common/compile:compile) scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found.
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed May 1, 2013 11:18:33 PM
```

Any idea what this is and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Adding `scala-library` as a project dependency:

```
"org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % "2.10.1"
```

Did the trick. Still not sure why this is necessary now but wasn't before.

Comment: I had the same problem and I fixed it by removing *all* extra files in my project. Not just all `target/` dirs, but all `project/target/` dirs as well (I think the latter was the one that solved it, and they weren't being removed by `sbt clean`).

Comment: I don't think it is the right solution. The *scala* lib should be pulled in automatically with the version specified by *scalaVersion*. You should try `sbt clean`, then rebuild everything.

Comment: This solution also works with `scala-maven-plugin` when using JDK 9+. Just add `scala-library` as compile or provided scope dependency to the project.

Answer (score 23):

The issue is when you clear all the project dependencies up while setting yours, i.e. using `:=` not `++=` or `+=` to add dependencies to `libraryDependencies` in a build definition, say in `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies := Dependencies.microservice
```

With `:=` all the current dependencies that sbt sets upfront in `libraryDependencies` are cleared out and the only available dependencies are these from `Dependencies.microservice` (as in the above example).

Adding up `"org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % "2.10.1"` (or whatever version of `scalaVersion` you use) is just a workaround for clearing out the already-properly-initialized `libraryDependencies` setting.

It's easily to reproduce with the following build definition - `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies := Seq()
```

Trying to compile Scala files results in the error - note `show libraryDependencies`:

```
➜  clear-library-dependencies  xsbt
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/java8/Contents/Home
SBT_OPTS= -Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins/}global-plugins...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to clear-library-dependencies (in build file:/Users/jacek/dev/sandbox/clear-library-dependencies/)
[clear-library-dependencies]> show libraryDependencies
[info] List()
[clear-library-dependencies]> compile
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/dev/sandbox/clear-library-dependencies/}clear-library-dependencies...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/jacek/dev/sandbox/clear-library-dependencies/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:compileIncremental for the full output.
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala.runtime in compiler mirror not found.
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Feb 3, 2015 10:36:08 PM
```

Change the build to the following (not usable, but just to show the point):

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq()
```

The result's going to be as follows:

```
[clear-library-dependencies]> reload
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Set current project to clear-library-dependencies (in build file:/Users/jacek/dev/sandbox/clear-library-dependencies/)
[clear-library-dependencies]> show libraryDependencies
[info] List(org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.4)
[clear-library-dependencies]> compile
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/dev/sandbox/clear-library-dependencies/}clear-library-dependencies...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/jacek/dev/sandbox/clear-library-dependencies/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Feb 3, 2015 10:38:19 PM
```

Answer (score 13):

The thing that ended up alleviating this error for me was downgrading my java version. I recently upgraded to Java 10 which seems to have compatibility issues with some versions of scala (at the very least it has problems with scala 2.12), so moving down to Java 8 did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, I had a similar issue that resolved itself when I removed the .ivy2 cache for scala and restarted sbt.