# Trying to cross compile a project to Scala 2.11 fails with "error while loading Object, Missing dependency 'object scala in compiler mirror'"

Tags: scala, sbt, cross-compiling, scala-2.11

I'm trying to compile my project to Scala 2.10 and 2.11 so that I can release versions for both scala versions, but every time I try to do it it fails with the following message:

```
#( 04/26/14@ 7:40 )( mauricio@Mauricios-MacBook-Pro ):~/projects/scala/postgresql-netty@scala-2.11✔
   sbt compile
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/mauricio/projects/scala/postgresql-netty/project
[info] Set current project to db-async-base (in build file:/Users/mauricio/projects/scala/postgresql-netty/)
[info] Compiling 61 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /Users/mauricio/projects/scala/postgresql-netty/db-async-common/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] error while loading Object, Missing dependency 'object scala in compiler mirror', required by /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/Object.class)
scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala in compiler mirror not found.
    at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:17)
    at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:18)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:53)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:66)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getPackage(Mirrors.scala:173)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ScalaPackage$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:161)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ScalaPackage(Definitions.scala:161)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ScalaPackageClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:162)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ScalaPackageClass(Definitions.scala:162)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1375)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1278)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0$$anon$2.<init>(CompilerInterface.scala:113)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:113)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:99)
    at xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:102)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:48)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:41)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(AggressiveCompile.scala:99)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:99)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:99)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.sbt$compiler$AggressiveCompile$$timed(AggressiveCompile.scala:166)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.compileScala$1(AggressiveCompile.scala:98)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:143)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:87)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:39)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:37)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(Incremental.scala:99)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:38)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:37)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:65)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:37)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:27)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile2(AggressiveCompile.scala:157)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile1(AggressiveCompile.scala:71)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:46)
    at sbt.Compiler$.apply(Compiler.scala:75)
    at sbt.Compiler$.apply(Compiler.scala:66)
    at sbt.Defaults$.sbt$Defaults$$compileTaskImpl(Defaults.scala:743)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:735)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:735)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[error] (db-async-common/compile:compile) scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala in compiler mirror not found.
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Apr 26, 2014 7:43:49 PM
```

My build file looks like this:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object ProjectBuild extends Build {

  val commonName = "db-async-common"
  val postgresqlName = "postgresql-async"
  val mysqlName = "mysql-async"

  lazy val root = Project(
    id = "db-async-base",
    base = file("."),
    settings = Configuration.baseSettings,
    aggregate = Seq(common, postgresql, mysql)
  )

  lazy val common = Project(
    id = commonName,
    base = file(commonName),
    settings = Configuration.baseSettings ++ Seq(
      name := commonName,
      libraryDependencies := Configuration.commonDependencies
    )
  )

  lazy val postgresql = Project(
    id = postgresqlName,
    base = file(postgresqlName),
    settings = Configuration.baseSettings ++ Seq(
      name := postgresqlName,
      libraryDependencies ++= Configuration.implementationDependencies
    )
  ) aggregate (common) dependsOn (common)

  lazy val mysql = Project(
    id = mysqlName,
    base = file(mysqlName),
    settings = Configuration.baseSettings ++ Seq(
      name := mysqlName,
      libraryDependencies ++= Configuration.implementationDependencies
    )
  ) aggregate (common) dependsOn (common)

}

object Configuration {

  val commonVersion = "0.2.13"
  val projectScalaVersion = "2.11.0"

  val specs2Dependency = "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.3.11" % "test"
  val logbackDependency = "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.13" % "test"

  val commonDependencies = Seq(
    "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.5",
    "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.3",
    "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "1.5",
    "io.netty" % "netty-all" % "4.0.18.Final",
    "org.javassist" % "javassist" % "3.18.1-GA",
    specs2Dependency,
    logbackDependency
  )

  val implementationDependencies = Seq(
    specs2Dependency,
    logbackDependency
  )

  val baseSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
    scalacOptions :=
      Opts.compile.encoding("UTF8")
        :+ Opts.compile.deprecation
        :+ Opts.compile.unchecked
        :+ "-feature"
    ,
    scalacOptions in doc := Seq("-doc-external-doc:scala=http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/"),
    scalaVersion := projectScalaVersion,
    crossScalaVersions := Seq(projectScalaVersion, "2.10.4"),
    javacOptions := Seq("-source", "1.6", "-target", "1.6", "-encoding", "UTF8"),
    organization := "com.github.mauricio",
    version := commonVersion,
    parallelExecution := false,
    publishArtifact in Test := false,
    publishMavenStyle := true,
    pomIncludeRepository := {
      _ => false
    },
    publishTo <<= version {
      v: String =>
        val nexus = "https://oss.sonatype.org/"
        if (v.trim.endsWith("SNAPSHOT"))
          Some("snapshots" at nexus + "content/repositories/snapshots")
        else
          Some("releases" at nexus + "service/local/staging/deploy/maven2")
    },
    pomExtra := (
      <url>https://github.com/mauricio/postgresql-async</url>
        <licenses>
          <license>
            <name>APACHE-2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
          </license>
        </licenses>
        <scm>
          <url>git@github.com:mauricio/postgresql-netty.git</url>
          <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:mauricio/postgresql-netty.git</connection>
        </scm>
        <developers>
          <developer>
            <id>mauricio</id>
            <name>Maurício Linhares</name>
            <url>https://github.com/mauricio</url>
          </developer>
        </developers>
      )
  )

}
```

And if you'd like to pull the source to check it's [at this branch on Github](https://github.com/mauricio/postgresql-async/tree/scala-2.11).

Any info on trying to fix this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is very simple, in your `Build.scala`, you did almost all right, but in commons project you had overridden default `commonDependencies`. By default it contains dependency to scala-library.

This piece of code

```
lazy val common = Project(
    id = commonName,
    base = file(commonName),
    settings = Configuration.baseSettings ++ Seq(
      name := commonName,
      libraryDependencies := Configuration.commonDependencies // #1
    )
  )
```

at the element marked as `#1` should have

```
libraryDependencies ++= Configuration.commonDependencies
```

Ps. I've sent you a pull request with the fix.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out and come back here!

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares any news on this one - did it help?

Comment: Now it builds, but when I execute `sbt publish-local` it only publishes the 2.10 version, doesn't build the 2.11 one.

Comment: Ignore me, forgot it had to be `sbt + publish-local`, now it's all working. Thanks for the PR and for figuring out the actual issue!

Answer (score 8):

I was getting this error when trying to use the Oracle Java 9 jvm on Ubuntu with sbt. Using the Java 8 jvm worked for me, though.

Comment: Ha! Fixed it for me

Answer (score 3):

I think you answered before your questions [Multimodule project build with SBT breaks with weird error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16339257/651140)

In this build add a line `"org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % projectScalaVersion,`:

```
 val commonDependencies = Seq(
    ..
    "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "1.5",
    "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % projectScalaVersion,
    "io.netty" % "netty-all" % "4.0.18.Final",
    ...
  )
```

Comment: I checked both branches and in current `"org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % projectScalaVersion` is missing. I tried to build with this line with success.

Comment: I forked and added line to build: [postgresql-async](https://github.com/ajozwik/postgresql-async/tree/scala-2.11)

Answer (score 2):

In `Build.scala` I would add `autoScalaLibrary := true`:

```
lazy val common = Project(
    id = commonName,
    base = file(commonName),
    settings = Configuration.baseSettings ++ Seq(
      ...
      autoScalaLibrary := true,
      ...
    )
  )
```

Answer (score -3):

This problem was solved for me when using intellij, by closing the project and reimporting it, and selecting sbt as the build system in settings.

Why oh why did I choose SBT?? Now I'm stuck with a very brittle build system. Thank God that atleast intellij does it right.

> sbt version: 0.13.15
>
> scala version: 2.12.1