# Error Adding Unmanaged Jar with SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a custom jar in my sbt project in the lib folder, where sbt automatically looks up any unmanaged jar but whenever i try sbt compile i am getting this error

---

```
scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
    at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:17)
    at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:18)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:53)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:45)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:45)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:66)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getClassByName(Mirrors.scala:102)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getRequiredClass(Mirrors.scala:105)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:257)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass(Definitions.scala:257)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1394)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1215)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0$$anon$2.<init>(CompilerInterface.scala:106)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:106)
    at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:95)
    at xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Comment: Why do you think it has anything to do with an unmanaged jar? Your build.sbt (or Build.scala) would be helpful.

Comment: Build.scala looks ok, works without adding the unmanaged jar in the lib folder

Comment: One possibility is that the jar is built for an incompatible Scala version (i.e. name ends in `_2.10` while you are using 2.11.x or vice versa). Another is that you are missing a dependency for the unmanaged jar. But that's a pretty strange error message.

Comment: Make sure you haven't overriden [Configuration.commonDependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23718946/2110188)