# Compile scala project with gradle: MissingRequirementError

Tags: scala, gradle

I have a project that used `SBT` before, I'm trying to compile it using `gradle` with scala plugin, but have got an exception as below:

> [ant:scalac] scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object
>   java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.

According to internet it's an issue with scala/zinc version incompatibility.
This project has scala 2.11 dependencies (and been built with scala library 2.11 before), so I've tried to add explicitly proper scala and zinc versions to dependencies (in various combinations), but results are the same.

```
dependencies {
    zinc 'com.typesafe.zinc:zinc:0.3.9'
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.6'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23718946

Comment: I've seen that topic. How to translate it into gradle? I though adding scala-library is what they suggest.

Comment: Please post all build files to help us investigate this further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was another error message, which I missed initially:

```
[ant:scalac] error: error while loading <root>, Error accessing ... activation\1.0.2\48d628027388ba84af265623c1434a70
bffdc175\activation-1.0.2.jar
```

Excluding this artifact from build resolved the issue:

```
    exclude group: 'activation', module: 'activation'
```