# MissingRequirementError with spark on datastax

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, datastax, spark-streaming

I'm trying to run a spark job on a datastax cluster. Jar file was compiled and built with sbt. But getting such error:

```
ERROR 2015-11-02 16:34:36 org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1446482076000 ms.0 scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object analytics.lib.database.package not found.
at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:16) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar:na]
at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:17) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar:na]
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.ensureModuleSymbol(Mirrors.scala:126) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar:na]
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.staticModule(Mirrors.scala:161) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar:na]
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.staticModule(Mirrors.scala:21) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar:na]
at analytics.app.AbstractIncomingBuzzes$$anonfun$2$$typecreator3$1.apply(IncomingBuzzes.scala:96) ~[analytics-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$WeakTypeTagImpl.tpe$lzycompute(TypeTags.scala:231) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar:na]
at scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$WeakTypeTagImpl.tpe(TypeTags.scala:231) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar:na]
at com.datastax.spark.connector.mapper.ColumnMapper$$typecreator1$1.apply(ColumnMapper.scala:54) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$WeakTypeTagImpl.tpe$lzycompute(TypeTags.scala:231) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar:na]
at scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$WeakTypeTagImpl.tpe(TypeTags.scala:231) ~[scala-reflect-2.10.5.jar:na]
at com.datastax.spark.connector.mapper.TupleColumnMapper.<init>(TupleColumnMapper.scala:12) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at com.datastax.spark.connector.mapper.ColumnMapper$.tuple1ColumnMapper(ColumnMapper.scala:54) ~[spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.4.0.jar:1.4.0]
at analytics.app.AbstractIncomingBuzzes$$anonfun$2.analytics$app$AbstractIncomingBuzzes$$anonfun$$eachRdd$1(IncomingBuzzes.scala:96) ~[analytics-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at analytics.app.AbstractIncomingBuzzes$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(IncomingBuzzes.scala:80) ~[analytics-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at analytics.app.AbstractIncomingBuzzes$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(IncomingBuzzes.scala:80) ~[analytics-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:631) ~[spark-streaming_2.10-1.4.1.1.jar:1.4.1.1]
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:631) ~[spark-streaming_2.10-1.4.1.1.jar:1.4.1.1]
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:42) ~[spark-streaming_2.10-1.4.1.1.jar:1.4.1.1]
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40) ~[spark-streaming_2.10-1.4.1.1.jar:1.4.1.1]
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40) ~[spark-streaming_2.10-1.4.1.1.jar:1.4.1.1]
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:399) ~[spark-streaming_2.10-1.4.1.1.jar:1.4.1.1]
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:40) ~[spark-streaming_2.10-1.4.1.1.jar:1.4.1.1]
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40) ~[spark-streaming_2.10-1.4.1.1.jar:1.4.1.1]
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40) ~[spark-streaming_2.10-1.4.1.1.jar:1.4.1.1]
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161) ~[scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:34) ~[spark-streaming_2.10-1.4.1.1.jar:1.4.1.1]
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:193) ~[spark-streaming_2.10-1.4.1.1.jar:1.4.1.1]
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:193) ~[spark-streaming_2.10-1.4.1.1.jar:1.4.1.1]
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:193) ~[spark-streaming_2.10-1.4.1.1.jar:1.4.1.1]
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57) ~[scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:192) ~[spark-streaming_2.10-1.4.1.1.jar:1.4.1.1]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
```

Any ideas what is wrong there? Tweaks like [MissingRequirementError with spark](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/MissingRequirementError-with-spark-td21149.html) and [why-does-sbt-build-fail-with-missingrequirementerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329566/why-does-sbt-build-fail-with-missingrequirementerror-object-scala-runtime-in-c) did not help.

Comment: Do you get this error building with SBT or do you get it on spark submit? Can you post some code -- a minimum verifiable example of the issue?

Comment: @phact SBT works fine. I get the error when do spark submit for generated jar. There is written own package `analytics.lib.database.package` for tables definitions. Called class `IncomingBuzzes.scala:96 ` imports this package. And spark submit fails here `val withEventInfo = databaseOps.withCassandraJoinType(
        input keyBy (_.eventId),
        Keyspace.api,
        Table.Api.event,
        "event_id"
       )((_, buzz, eventInfo: EventAnalyticsStats) =>
        (buzz, eventInfo)).cache`. `Keyspace.api`, `Table.Api.event` are from `analytics.lib.database.package`

Comment: 96th line is `)((_, buzz, eventInfo: EventAnalyticsStats) =>`

Comment: ```def withCassandraJoinType[
    K : ClassTag, T : ClassTag, U <: Serializable : ClassTag, R : ClassTag](
    input: RDD[(K, T)],
    keyspace: String,
    table: String,
    joinOn: ColumnRef)(
    f: (K, T, U) => R)(
    implicit rwf: RowWriterFactory[Tuple1[K]],
    rrf: RowReaderFactory[U])
      : RDD[R]
```

Comment: Did you define EventAnalyticsStats?

Comment: Sure. That is a class which uses `com.datastax.spark.connector.SomeColumns` - `object EventAnalyticsStats {
  val columnSelector =
    SomeColumns(...
    )
}` I think otherwise it'd not be compilable with SBT.

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem ? Still facing the issue with Spark - 1.6.2 and datastax 1.6.0-M1